# Saving tinymce textarea content to file

Tags: php, tinymce

I have been trying to save tinymce editor textarea content to a .txt file for a while but without success yet.
This is my html file code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinyMCE example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5 Basic template">
  <meta name="author" content="R Dickinson">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
// General options
mode : "textareas",

});
</script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
<h1>test tinymce save</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <p> 
        <textarea name="content" style="width:50%"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>     
</form>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Now test.php

```
<?php
/*
 * test.php
  */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>test tiny mce</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.21" />
</head>

<body>
<?php

echo(stripslashes($_POST['content']));
?>
<?php
$file = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
$data =(stripslashes($_POST['content']));
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
?>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm grateful for helpful replies to fix this-many thanks :-)

**Update**
Following the first answer below I have added triggerSave as:

```
 <script language="Javascript">
function submitForm() {
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<p> 
    <textarea name="content" style="width:50%"></textarea>
    <!--<input type="submit" value="Save" />-->
    <a href="javascript:submitForm();">Submit Form</a>
</p>
```

but still no success...More help gratefully received

**UPDATE 2**
Here is my jQuery TinyMCE version:

```
 <!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample WebPage</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5 Basic template">
  <meta name="author" content="R Dickinson-see sitepoint etc">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3");
</script>
<!-- Load jQuery build -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas"
});
</script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section>


<!-- OF COURSE YOU NEED TO ADAPT ACTION TO WHAT PAGE YOU WANT TO LOAD WHEN HITTING "SAVE" -->
<form method="post" action="show.php">
        <p>     
                <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.</textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
</form>

    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is the file created? Is it empty? Does server return some error? Is $_POST filled?

Comment: Do you have write permission on the file?

Comment: The problem is that text I enter into the textarea is not saved to text file! I have the file data.txt already in directory & it has writable permissions. I am testing this with IIS server in inetpub>wwwroot> Grateful for more help

Answer (score 8):

The question itself comes down to :

> How to save HTML content of TinyMCE into a file.

Well, first of all, you need:

1) Get content of editor
2) Send this content to PHP script
3) Implement some function that would save that content into a file

**Getting content** 

Make sure you are getting it the way it should work.

For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

  var btn = document.getElementById('SubmitBtn');

  btn.onclick = function(){

     //This MUST alert HTML content of editor.
     alert( tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() );
  }
}

</script>

<input type="button" id="SubmitBtn" value="Get HTML content"/>
```

**Sending content to PHP script**

All you need to do is to send value of the method `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` to PHP script.

Well, you should use `Jquery-AJAX` for that.

Assume that you included `jquery.js` into script tag in the head section, the next step would be **sending JavaScript variable to PHP script**

It would be similar to this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  var url = "path_to_your_php_script.php";

  $("#SomeSubmitButton").click(function(){
    //"content" will PHP variable 
    $.post(url, { "content" : tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }, function(respond){

       if ( respond == ){
          alert('Content saved to file');
          return;
       } else {
          //Error message assumed
          alert(respond);
        }
    });
  });

});

</script>
```

**PHP script**

Since we were sending `"content"` this one will be populated in `$_POST` superglobal

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['content']) ){

   //This is what you want - HTML content from tinyMCE
   //just treat this a string

   if ( save_html_to_file($_POST['content'], '/some_file.html') ){
     //Print 1 and exit script
     die(1);
   } else {
      die('Couldnt write to stream');
   }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param string $content HTML content from TinyMCE editor
 * @param string $path File you want to write into
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save_html_to_file($content, $path){
   return (bool) file_put_contents($path, $content);
}
```

So after execution this you should get back `alert` with message of success.

Comment: Thanks metal_fan-your code gives an alertbox with html code in it-could you please add the code to save the text from tinymce editor textarea to a text file (my original question!).Ha apologies-I have just seen your save to file function! I will try & implement it & report back! Cheers :-)

Comment: I have spent some time trying to fix this with no success-can you please edit my 2 files (.html/.php)with your code implementation & post them here? I am most grateful for your further help-thank you

Comment: @rpd you don't need to use `stripslashes()` nor `fopen()` nor `fwrite()` and the biggest error out there - you don't have to submit the form if it has tinyMCE instance. The HTML content from tinyMCE safe enough (tinyMCE filters it itself)

Comment: The code gives an alertbox. This is what you need, you asked for. You need to save that given string into a file. Right? Then you need to send that string to PHP script and process/handle it there.

Comment: Thanks for your help metal_fan. I have tried to get your write to file function to work but I still haven't got it to work.  Can you please edit my 2 original files (.html/.php) with an implementation of your code to help me out here? I would be very grateful if you could help further & I appreciate your help-thank you

Comment: @rpd your code above - it's not that enough. There's a jquery version for TinyMCE, are you aware of? One thing that would make life easier. Please update your code with jquery and let me know as soon as you do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20458/discussion-between-rpd-and-metal-fan)

Comment: @all: be aware that using the jQuery tinymce build is slow and leads to problems in many cases - i advide most users to use the regular tinymce build

Answer (score 0):

You should update your TinyMCE instances before submitting your form. Use this javascript:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

I usually put this in a function and call it on `onsubmit` event of form.

There is already different questions around this topic in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what you mean especially as I am using TinyMCE editor (not CKEditor). Can you explain a bit more please with TinyMCE code? Thanks

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I was reading your title wrong! Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit to TinyMCE from your original CKEditor instance--I have tried implementing triggerSave as I edited my question but no success yet..

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your implementation. I try different things on my code in these situations. Put a name for your form and do other stuffs. Try to `var_dump()` your `$_POST['content']`. I think step by step tracing will help.